# Knex.js One to Many table join

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, join, knex.js

The scenario:

quotes tables:
`first_name, email, estimate, etc.`

quote_notes:
`id, note, quote_id`

So, quotes has_many quote_notes. I am trying to join that when doing my query in my quote model.

```js
function getAllNotes() {
  return db('quote_notes')
    .select('quote_notes.id', 'note', 'quote_notes.created_at', 'quote_id')
    .join('quotes', 'quote_notes.quote_id', 'quotes.id')
    .orderBy('id')
}
```

Whenever I do the get request to the path, it returns all quote_notes for any quote I look at.

```js
router.get('/:id/notes', (req, res) => {
  const {id} = req.params;

  Quotes.getAllNotes(id).then((users) => {
    res.status(200).json(users);
  });
});
```

This is my request for reference:

```js
const getQuoteNotes = async () => {
  let quoteNotes = await axiosWithAuth().get('/quotes/' + quoteId + '/notes');
  setQuoteNotes(quoteNotes.data);
  }
```

And my table for quote_notes:

```js
table.bigInteger('quote_id')
      .unsigned()
      .index()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('quotes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Join should be used before select

```
return db('quote_notes')
  .join('quotes', 'quotes.id','=', 'quote_notes.quote_id')
  .select('quote_notes.id', 'note', 'quote_notes.created_at', 'quote_id')
  .orderBy('id')
```

Your last edit changes things, if you just want the notes of certain quote you should query for the notes by `quote_id`

```
db('quote_notes')
.where('quote_id', quoteId )
.orderBy('id')
```

Comment: it still returns it on every quotes request. select does not have to necessarily come after the join. Do I have to join quote_notes on the quotes table or quotes on the quote_notes.?

Comment: my bad i edited the `.join('quotes', 'quotes.id','=', 'quote_notes.quote_id')`  you just need to make sure that column names and IDs match on the other table, did you set `quote_notes.quote_id` up as foreign key for quotes?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up, so you're saying the is not need to join the tables?

Comment: a join query returns the tables data with additional columns from another table so it wasn't the right way for your case, say you have a `users` table with `name` column and the `quotes` table had `user_id`, and `quote_text` columns, you can join users with quotes and get the quotes data with user name `.select('users.name', 'quote.text')`

Comment: Thank you, that really clears it up for me.